# In Puerto Rico when using the "residence" how is "occupied island spaces" interpreted?

Tags: puerto-rico

When playing Puerto Rico and using the residence building it states that it is based on the number of "occupied island spaces".

Does this mean plantation spaces with a farm and a colonist? Or does this mean plantation space with or without a colonist?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It means just a plantation, no colonists are required.

From the rules:

> Residence The owner of the occupied residence earns, at game end,
> additional victory points for the plantations and quarries he has
> placed on his island. For up to nine filled island spaces, he earns 4
> VP, for ten filled island spaces, he earns 5 VP, for eleven filled
> island spaces, he earns 6 VP, and for all twelve spaces filled, he
> earns 7 VP.
>
> *Example: at game end, the owner of the occupied residence
> has filled 10 of his 12 island spaces with plantations and quarries:
> he earns an additional 5 VP.*

No requirement for colonists.

Comment: I just find it odd that it specified that the "occupied residence" means a colonist on the residence but the "occupied island spaces" does not mean a colonist on the island spaces.

Comment: @alex, they definitely could have been clearer, this question comes up a lot for new players.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure Lance Roberts' answer is correct. For the Mayor, the rules say this: "If there is at least one colonist on a tile, it is considered occupied. Only occupied tiles may use their functions; unoccupied tiles *never* function!" (emphasis theirs).

Given that emphasis on the word 'occupied' on the residence card, and the word 'never' in the mayor description, it could be interpreted as island spaces without a colonist do not contribute towards the residence card's ability, as they are not occupied and do not function.

This ambiguity could be fixed by changing the word 'occupied' in relation to the island tiles on the residence card.

Comment: The other answer is definitely correct, but your reasoning is reasonable given that the rules don't use the clearest language. The difference is that the rules you are quoting are discussing the definition of an "occupied tile", while Residence deals with "occupied island spaces". And while unoccupied buildings "never function"; they DO count for points at the end of the game.